# how can i resize title bar back, minimize and close button in .net maui

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit, .net-maui.shell

[image: 1]

how can I resize this.

im try some of code but no one works

Comment: You mentioned you tried something. What did you try? Why didn't work? Did you get any exceptions? Any error messages? Any output that will help us further and not repeat the same steps that you already took? We're going to need a bit more info here to make this a useful question and actually have a chance at getting an answer.

Comment: Does this help? [MAUI why is my title bar gray and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74570449/maui-why-is-my-title-bar-gray-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Seems you could customize the titlebar: [Blazor Hybrid (MAUI) Application - Window Customization at Runtime (when Targeting Windows)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/914870/blazor-hybrid-(maui)-application-window-customizat)